# How do I select friend ids using the facebook api?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-3.0

Whenever I call `FB.ApiRequest()` to send invites it brings up a native facebook menu to quickly select friends.

Is there any similar call which would allow me to select friend's user ids in a similar manner/interface like above.

I want to do this so that a user can monitor only selected friend's scores in an app.

This is my first time playing around with the facebook api, and I couldn't find much info about this in fb's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `/me/friends` after authorizing with the `user_friends` permission and develop your own selector. Keep in mind that you can only get friends who authorized the App too.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. How would I be able to call only selected friends in the above call? (say if I had an array of 20 friend user ids selected by the user).

Comment: not sure how it works with the ios sdk, but the apprequest dialog offers a "to" parameter where you can use a comma separated list of friend ids.